# Getting POST request data using Firefox or Chrome Network Monitor

Tags: json, post, xmlhttprequest, content-type

I am trying to examine POST request data for XHR requests using either Firefox or Chrome Network Monitor tools.  When examining these requests, the Content-Type request header is application/json.  When looking for the request data, either by examining Request > Request Payload in Firefox[1], or Payload > Request Payload in Chrome, I do not get anything which appears like a JSON string showing key:value pairs.  Instead, I get a string which appears like a base64 string, something like:

XO9z3xY2QMLKtxJaK0WT2xI0JRxV6/F+7g3zIZLY9lXjmVe9k+Rcd1h+NjJ7KtabND7/b0cF+nDuGyXzfGTHbf6xbPgsmpxdMmbQI7fL65lK0dqxBd1BLJissinYhRdN

The raw/not-raw (Firefox) or source/parsed (Chrome) options show the same string.

Is there a reason I do not see anything which appears like JSON in the payload?  Or is there a way to interpret this string which would show key:value pairs?

These requests are being sent to a surveillance camera; they are sent whenever adjustments are made to the camera, such as zoom, focus, brightness, etc.  They have query strings which includes a key corresponding to the function being adjusted (eg, cmd=PtzCtrl for a pan-tilt-zoom adjustment) so I am assuming they are sending data for the given command.  As the query string contains no other data which would tell what to set the function (eg, zoom) to, I am assuming the value is contained in the POST data.  In fact, when I examine *any* XHR POST requests sent to the camera, the payload always appears in the form expressed above, even though the Content-Type header is application/json.

[1] https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Network_Monitor/request_details